# mutate and if_any with condition over multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, mutate

I tried to combine mutate, case_when and if_any to create a variable = 1 if any of the variables whose name begins with "string" is equal to a specific string.
I can't figure out what I'm missing in the combination of these conditions.

I'm trying:

```
df <-data.frame(string1= c("a","b", "c"), string2= c("d", "a", "f"), string3= c("a", "d", "c"), id= c(1,2,3))

df <- df%>% 
      mutate(cod = case_when(if_any(starts_with("string") == "a" ~1 )))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax was slightly wrong, but you were close. Note that `if_any` works like `across`, so like this `if_any(columns, condition)`, and you should use `function`, `\` or `~` to specify the condition.

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(cod = case_when(if_any(starts_with("string"), ~ .x == "a") ~ 1))

  string1 string2 string3 id cod
1       a       d       a  1   1
2       b       a       d  2   1
3       c       f       c  3  NA
```